# Any procedure to find a normal operator that is not self adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there a quick algorithm or tricks (that someone who is half way through Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right would understand) to come up with a linear map that is normal but not self-adjoint (say for a simple operator over a 2 dimensional inner product space), that would be pretty handy to get some intuition quickly in an exam situation?

I ask because it always takes me a while to come up with an example, and usually its a very basic one. If any external condition was imposed on this map, I wouldn't be able to come up with one quickly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a skew-adjoint operator, like $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
An easy way to remember this example is that if you identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$, then this operator is multiplication by $\sqrt{-1}$.  (That is not a coincidence...)

Indeed, every normal operator (over the reals) can be written as the sum of a self-adjoint operator and a skew-adjoint operator which commute with each other.